# What are the time complexity of these two codes

Tags: python, big-o, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

Following are two different dynamic programming codes for fibonacci series. I cannot figure out the time complexity of these. Results of both are the same. Any help is appreciated.

```
#Code 1
def fibo(n) :
    if mem[n] is not None:
        return mem[n]

    if n == 1 or n == 2 :
        res = 1
    else :
        res = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)

    mem[n] = res
    return res

n = int(input("Enter position :"))
mem = [None] * (n + 1)
fibo(n)
```

## Code 2

```
def fibo(n) :
    if len(mem) == n-1 :
        return mem[n-1]

    if n == 1 or n == 2 :
        res = 1
    else :
        res = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)

    mem.append(res)
    return res

n = int(input("Enter position :"))
mem = []
fibo(n)
```

Comment: Do you have any thoughts or guesses?

Comment: For the 1st one it is O(n) but not sure about the next